# Could not load file or assemble for iAnywhere.Data.Sqlanywhere

Tags: asp.net, .net, sybase, sqlanywhere

I published my website application to one of my client side server and got the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere, Version=11.0.1.20442, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

### Server Details:

Windows 2012 64bit version

I published my application from Visual Studio 2008. 
So the framework version is 3.5.

DB: Sybase - Sqlanywhere 16.

It would be great someone can explain about the GAC settings or what do I need to do understand. I am a beginner.

Thanks

Comment: where did you deploy it? is it in the bin? did you need to install this so that its in the GAC?

Comment: Thanks. I am a beginner. How can I install this into the GAC?

Comment: Is there an install for that component?

Comment: Yes and I added that dll into the component before publish my website. But the version changed from 11 to 16.